# Type mismatch issue of sub1

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I can't figure out why the sub1 function in pick1 has type mismatch issue,but pick0 don't

```
(define-predicate one? One)
(: pick1 (-> Positive-Integer (Listof Any) Any))
(define pick1
  (λ(n lat)
    (cond [(one? n) (car lat)]
          [else (pick1 (sub1 n)
                       (cdr lat))])))
```

I have tried this workaround,
but I think this is not a right way to fix this issue.

```
(: pick1-workaround (-> Positive-Integer (Listof Any) Any))
(define pick1-workaround 
  (λ(n lat)
    (cond [(one? n) (car lat)]
          [else (pick1-workaround  (cast (sub1 n) Positive-Integer)
                                   (cdr lat))])))
```

pick0 don't have this issue.

```
;;(: pick0 (-> Natural (Listof Any) Any))
(define pick0
  (λ(n lat)
    (cond [(zero? n) (car lat)]
          [else (pick0 (sub1 n)
                       (cdr lat))])))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you implicitly want Typed Racket to reason is that if `x` is in `Positive-Integer - One`, then `(sub1 x)` is in `Positive-Integer`. While it is easy for human to see that this is true, I think the problem is that Typed Racket does not know how to describe `Positive-Integer - One` = `{2, 3, 4, ...}`.

On the other hand, your `pick0` works. This version of `pick1` also works:

```
(: pick1 (-> Positive-Integer (Listof Any) Any))
(define pick1
  (λ (n lat)
    (define n* (sub1 n))
    (cond 
      [(zero? n*) (car lat)]
      [else (pick1 n* (cdr lat))])))
```

I think the reason is that Typed Racket knows that if `x` is in `Positive-Integer`, then `(sub1 x)` is in `Natural`, and it recognizes that `(sub1 x)` in the else branch must be in `Natural - {0} = Positive-Integer` (via [occurrence typing](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/occurrence-typing.html)), allowing it to successfully type check the program.